# Laravel 5.5 + image not readable error (used Intervention\Image)

Tags: php, laravel-5, resize

I used ImageOptimizer package for reducing image size. Source: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

In controller:

```
if (Input::hasFile('title_image')) {

    $Product = Input::file('title_image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $Product->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($Product)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) )->move(public_path() . '/../../products', md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png");

    $product->title_img = "products/" . md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png";

    }
```

How can I fix this error???:

> image not readable

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRealPath()` when you upload an image.

```
if (Input::hasFile('title_image')) {

    $Product = Input::file('title_image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $Product->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($Product->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) )->move(public_path() . '/../../products', md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png");

    $product->title_img = "products/" . md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png";
}
```